# android how to hide system bar?

Tags: android, spinner

i want to know how can i hide system bar under when i click on a spinner because i have 2 spinner and when i click on them they show me the system bar but i dont want to see it so someone can tell me how can i do to hide it when i click on a spinner button please ?

```
        final ActionBar action = getActionBar();

    civilite = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.civilite);
    date_naissance = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.date_naissance);
    nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);
    prenom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prenom);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email); 

    civilite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);

            action.hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Some Window flags can only be set in onCreate, before you call setContentView, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: yes i agree with your answer and in my onCreate i have this flags too but doesn't too

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has to do with how you configure ActionBar and the order of calls. While not really an answer to your problem, I post here how I do in my App to show / hide it:

First of all, I declare in the `styles.xml`, in the Theme for the `Activity`, the settings so `ActionBar` will be Overlaid your application window. This allows you to use 100% of the screen height, and the actionbar, if present, will be rendered over your content:

```
 <style name="Nebular.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
 </style>
```

Either add those `<item>` to your existing theme, or add the whole `<style>` in **styles.xml** then declare in the `Manifest` that your `activity` uses it:

```
    <activity
        android:name="blahblah"
        .
        .
        android:theme="@style/Nebular.ActionBar" >
```

Now you shouldn't have any problem at all to hide or show the actionbar:

- `action.hide()` will hide the actionbar (action is from your code)
- `action.show()` will show it.

I don't know if it's possible to hide & show the `actionbar` if it's **not** in overlay mode. Your attempt to switch to full screen should do the trick, but mind that *any touch when in fullscreen causes to exit fullscreen mode*.